# checked checkbox in edit page if value existed

Tags: php

I have categories in the database and the admin can check multiple categories but in the edit I want to show checked box if admin added category previously

```
$rows = $util->get_all_categories();
$crows = $util->get_categories_by_user_id($id);


                if($rows) {
                    //all the categories are in $rows array and the $crows carry shows already added categories
                    foreach ($rows as $row) {
                        
                          //this exper work but checked only one checkbox
                        if( $row['name'] == $crow['name']){
                        echo '<label class="block"><input type="checkbox" name="category" checked value="' . $row['ID'] . '"> ' . $row['name'] . '</label>';
                        echo '<br>';
                        }else{
                        echo '<label class="block"><input type="checkbox" name="category" value="' . $row['ID'] . '"> ' . $row['name'] . '</label>';
                        echo '<br>';
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }?>
```

in the photo below you can see it is only checks one checkbox where have multiple
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kfsr.png

Comment: so, what is wrong ?

Comment: well there is multiple categories to be checked it is only checking one

Comment: $crows = $util->get_categories_by_user_id($id);
What are crows ? Can I have example array or something.

Comment: I mean what you expect when you $crow['name'] ? Actually where $crow comes from ? I cant see anything like foreach ($crows as $crow) { } or something

Comment: $crows is an array contain categories id and categories name on user_id so it just returns the categories id and categories name that the user had added previosly but $rows contain all the categories id and categories name in the data base , and I want the ones in $crows checked already so the admin won't checked them again

Comment: I think the name confused you but it is just a variable name consider it $row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Let's be clear.
I can't get where $crow['name'] come from. Because you didn't parse $crows array. It's undefined.

But as for how to do it with the necessary information:

```
<?php
// lets say $util->get_all_categories(); gives you this
$rows = [['ID'=>1, 'name'=>'r1'],['ID'=>2, 'name'=>'r2'],['ID'=>3,'name'=>'r3']];

// and $util->get_categories_by_user_id($id); gives you this
$crows = ['r2', 'r1'];

if($rows) {
  foreach ($rows as $row) {                     
    if(in_array($row['name'],$crows)){
      echo '<label class="block"><input type="checkbox" name="category" checked value="' . $row['ID'] . '"> ' . $row['name'] . '</label>';
      echo '<br>';
    }else{
      echo '<label class="block"><input type="checkbox" name="category" value="' . $row['ID'] . '"> ' . $row['name'] . '</label>';
      echo '<br>';
    }                        
  }                 
}

?>
```

Your get_categories_by_user_id($id) function has to give u an array that bundle of user categories as expect as its name. In my example ['r2','r1']. Otherwise you have to parse it as how you parsed $rows array foreach ($rows as $row). And this causes the output to be repeated and more messy. (double loop).

---

Extra => If you want to do the same with less code:

```
<?php

$rows = [['ID'=>1, 'name'=>'r1'],['ID'=>2, 'name'=>'r2'],['ID'=>3, 'name'=>'r3']];
$crows = ['r2', 'r1'];

if($rows) {
    foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
        <label class="block">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category" <?php echo in_array($row['name'],$crows) ? 'checked' : '';?>  value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?>
        </label>
    <?php
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: yeah that worked although I needed to this as you noticed `$crows = $util->get_category_by_user_ID($u_id);
    $categories_array = array();
    foreach ($crows as $row) {
        $categories_array[] = $row['id'];
    }`